# Create chart online with c#?

Tags: c#, charts

I'm number textbox the value is always changing.
Now, I want to create a chart with the same values.
It means that I create an online chart.
But what I did not find answered in searching sites

Please help me...

Comment: I don't understand what you are heading for, please put in more details. Do you want to add a chart via Interop in Excel or in Win Forms or in asp.net mvc?

Comment: Really 'online'? Or 'live' or 'dynamic'..? Maybe you simply want to add new Datapoints to a Chart from your TextBox when a Button is pressed or the user hits enter?? Maybe, maybe, maybe..

Comment: My friends,I want to change any time chart values.

Comment: And this will be done at runtime

Comment: Please expand your question! Explain in detail what you have and what the user will do. Do not let us guess! Be clear! What does ',I want to change any time chart values' mean? change old values? add new values? or what??

Answer (score -1):

there is many chart template for c# in code project
here you are
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=chart%20in%20c%23%20site%3Acodeproject.com